# styling a jquery rotator with css

Tags: jquery, css, rotator

I am having trouble styling my jquery image rotator. I am still pretty new to web. I got the rotator to work for two monitor sizes, but I can't get it to work for a 320 width screen. It seems to have something to do with .mycaption because I'm getting a weird bar at the the top of the slider.

Here is the html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="en-US" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/">
    <head>
        <title>Design • Fabrication • Installation, Dallas | DSArts</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#slider').cycle({

                fx: 'fade',
                timeout: 4000,
                next: '#next',
                prev: '#prev',
                pause: 1


            });

            $('#next, #prev').hover(
                function() {
                    $('#slider').cycle('pause');
                },
                function() {
                    $('#slider').cycle('resume');
                });
        </script>

        <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
        <link href="small.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-width: 1056px)">
        <link href="mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px)">
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#3097B9">
        <div class="page-wrap">
            <header>
                <div id="headerwrap">
                    <div>
                        <a href="index.html">
                            <img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="DS Arts logo" width="529" height="143" class="headerimage" />
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <img src="images/Factory.png" alt="" width="400" height="136" id="buildingimg" />
                </div>
            </header>
            <div id="navwrap">
                <nav id="navbar">
                    <ul>
                        <p><a href="index.html">Home</a>
                        </p>
                        <p><a href="design.html">Design</a>
                        </p>
                        <p><a href="solutions.html">Solutions</a>
                        </p>
                        <p><a href="fabrication.html">Fabrication</a>
                        </p>
                        <p><a href="installation.html">Installation</a>
                        </p>
                        <p><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
                        </p>
                        <p><a href="clientlist.html">Client List</a>
                        </p>
                        <p><a href="contact.html" id="16">Contact</a>
                        </p>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div id="wrapper">
                <div id="paragraph">
                    <h1><a href="design.html">Design</a>, Display,<br> <a href="fabrication.html">Fabrication</a>,<br> <a href="installation.html">Installation</a>...</h1>
                    <p class="p">DS ARTS creates amazing environments that motivate, impress and make a statement. Through our design, production and installation expertise, we work with a wide spectrum of clients to create trade shows, special events, showrooms, restaurant and retail
                        interiors, sales and marketing centers, specialized decor and entertainment venues. Of course, everything is created with each client’s unique needs in mind. Take a look we think you’ll like what you see.</p>
                    <div class="icon">
                        <img src="images/icon_home.png" alt="" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="rotator">
                    <div id="hero">
                        <div id="next">
                            <img src="images/right.png" width="50" height="50" alt="" />
                        </div>
                        <div id="prev">
                            <img src="images/left.png" width="50" height="50" alt="" />
                        </div>
                        <div id="slider">
                            <div id="slidewrap">
                                <img src="images/conan.jpg" alt="scenic stage" />
                                <span class="myCaption">CONAN O'BRIEN SHOW - MAJESTIC THEATER - Dallas</span>
                            </div>
                            <div id="slidewrap">
                                <img src="images/mickey.jpg" alt="display graphics" />
                                <span class="myCaption">MATTEL - New York Toy Fair</span>
                            </div>
                            <div id="slidewrap">
                                <img src="images/Lenox square.jpg" alt="stryrofoam sculpture" />
                                <span class="myCaption">LENOX SQUARE MALL - Atlanta</span>
                            </div>
                            <div id="slidewrap">
                                <img src="images/fisher.jpg" alt="Fisher Price" />
                                <span class="myCaption">FISHER PRICE JPMA SHOW - Dallas</span>
                            </div>
                            <div id="slidewrap">
                                <img src="images/DSC03399.JPG" alt="lighting" />
                                <span class="myCaption">VICTORY PARK DISCOVERY CENTER - Dallas</span>
                            </div>
                            <div id="slidewrap">
                                <img src="images/megazord.jpg" alt="styrofoam sculpture" />
                                <span class="myCaption">BANDAI - New York Toy Fair</span>
                            </div>
                            <div id="slidewrap">
                                <img src="images/BIRD CAGES.jpg" alt="Cowboys Stadium" />
                                <span class="myCaption">COWBOYS STADIUM - Arlington</span>
                            </div>
                            <div id="slidewrap">
                                <img src="images/benten.jpg" alt="toy fair" />
                                <span class="myCaption">BANDAI - New York Toy Fair</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <footer class="site-footer">
            <div id="footwrap">
                <div itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/organization">
                    <span itemprop="name">DS Arts</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <span itemprop="street-address">1111 South Lamar Street</span>
                    <span itemprop="locality">Dallas</span>, <span itemprop="region">TX</span>
                    <span itemprop="postal-code">75215</span>
                    <span itemprop="country-name">USA</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <p>Phone:&nbsp;<span itemprop="telephone">214-565-7858</span> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <p>Fax:&nbsp;<span itemprop="fax">214-565-7859</span>
                    </p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <a href="mailto:dkolbo@dsarts.com" itemprop="email"> dkolbo@dsarts.com</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS.

```
@charset "utf-8";
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.page-wrap {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
body {
    margin: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 320px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
body header {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1.00);
    width: 320px;
    height: 105px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px rgba(0,0,0,1.00);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px rgba(0,0,0,1.00);
}
.headerimage {
    margin-top: 15px;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    overflow-x: visible;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 260px;
    height: auto;
}
.rotator {
    float: left;
    overflow-x: visible;
    margin-top: 33px;
    margin-bottom: 130px;
    position:relative;
}
#hero {
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    width:290px;
    height:227px;
}
#slider {
    position: relative;
    width: 290px;
    height: 227px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1.00);
    display: block;
}
#slidewrap {
    position: fixed;
    width:290px;
    height:227px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1.00);
}
#slidewrap img {
    width:290px;
    height:227px;
}
.myCaption {
    color: #F6F0E2;
    font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: x-small;
    z-index: 99;
    padding-left: 15px;
    display: block;
    width: 290px;
}
#next {
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    right: 0px;
    z-index: 99;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
    padding-right: 5px;
    display:none;
}
#prev {
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left::0px;
    z-index: 99;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
    padding-left: 5px;
    display:none;
}
#hero:hover #next {
    opacity: .8;
    transition: all .5s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-out;
}
#hero:hover #prev {
    opacity: .8;
    transition: all .5s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-out;
}
#wrapper script {
    width: 320px;
    height: 400px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    overflow-x: visible;
    overflow-y: visible;
}
#wrapper {
    width: 320px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    clear: left;
    float: left;
}
#navwrap {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1.00);
    height: 43px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px rgba(0,0,0,1.00);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px rgba(0,0,0,1.00);
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 0px;
    display:none;
}


#navbar {
    width: 320px;
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    display: inline;
}


#navbar ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: small;
    height: 50px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#navbar a {
    text-align: center;
    overflow-x: no-content;
    width: 12.5%;
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    height: 50px;
}
a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #f6f0e2;
}
a:visited {
    color: rgba(246,240,226,1.00);

}
a:hover , a:active, a:focus{
    color: #bf301a;
}
.p {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: #f6f0e2;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 300px;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
#paragraph {
    padding-top: 25px;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    width: 290px;
}
#paragraph .p {
    display: inline;
    padding-top: 15px;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 270px;
    line-height: 17px;

}
h1 {
    font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: #F6F0E2;
    font-size: x-large;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    float: left;
    line-height: 28px;
    width: 320px;

}
#headerwrap {
    width: 320px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
}
#map {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px rgba(0,0,0,1.00);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px rgba(0,0,0,1.00);
    margin-bottom: 80px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    line-height: normal;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin-top: 30px;
    display: block;
}
#columnwrap {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 320px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
}
#columnwrap p {
    width: 44%;
    float: left;
    color: rgba(246,240,226,1.00);
    font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: medium;
    margin-top: 30px;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 70px;
}
#buildingimg {
    margin-top: 40px;
    display: none;
    float: right;
}

.site-footer {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px rgba(0,0,0,1.00);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px rgba(0,0,0,1.00);
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1.00);
    float: left;
    margin-top: -60px;
    clear: both;
}
#footwrap {
    width: 320px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}

#footwrap div {
    color: #F6F0E2;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
    padding-top: 5px;
    font-size: 11px;
}
#footwrap div p {
    display: inline;
}

#portfoliowrapsmall {
    margin-top: 33px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-bottom: 70px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 20px rgba(0,0,0,1.00);
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 20px rgba(0,0,0,1.00);
    font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
    overflow-x: visible;
    width: 960px;
    float: left;
    display: none;
}

#portfoliowrap {
    margin-top: 33px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-bottom: 70px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 20px rgba(0,0,0,1.00);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 20px rgba(0,0,0,1.00);
    font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
    overflow-x: visible;
    width: 960px;
    float: left;
    display: none;
}
#contactinfo {
    float: left;
    padding-top: 35px;
    margin-left: 30px;
}
.icon {
    clear: left;
    padding-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0;
}
.icon img  {
    height: 180px;
    width: 180px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #000000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #000000;
    border-radius: 125px;
    border-collapse: collapse;

}
```

I have been trying to work this out for a while. Like I said, I'm teaching myself and I'm not sure where to start sometimes. I really appreciate any help that I can get.

Here's a jsfiddle of the code:  http://jsfiddle.net/v3c9s771/2/

Comment: A jsfiddle or plunker would probably help a lot here.  Thanks for posting your code, though.  Too many people neglect to post code.

Comment: I'm not sure that I'm using jsfiddle correctly. http://jsfiddle.net/mytaquitos/v3c9s771/

Comment: I fixed it to point to a CDN for the cycle plugin.  http://jsfiddle.net/v3c9s771/2/

Comment: Seems to be working fine. I made a jsfiddle earlier when you first posted and it worked also. Gotta replicate your problem for us :p

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/4hLyWIo.jpg

Comment: It seems to be working alright in the jsfiddle, but the .mycaption doesn't have a black background like it's supposed to. Above is an image of what it looks like in a browser.

Comment: It may be related to other css on your site, not what is included in the jsfiddle. A link to your site might help?

Comment: www.dsarts.com   The mobile css isn't included online yet.

Comment: Don't see the bar you describe  on a small screen.

Comment: It shows up in chrome when I use mobile emulation in developer tools.

Comment: Surreal Dreams, I don't see what you changed.

Comment: What did I do wrong in my jsfiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/mytaquitos/1bzo2ugx/

Comment: Well, thanks for your help everyone. I'll figure it out eventually. I just started learning this stuff. I don't have a formal education. I'm just barely starting to get this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I'm finding it hard to workout your problem.

From what I've worked out I assume your image is sizing strangely on this (320px) smaller device.

```
#slidewrap img {
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
```

Changing the image to fill the parent div might help you. Though your fiddle(s) aren't helping the diagnosis any.